# Change Display of Subscripts and Superscripts of Summations in a left bracket

Tags: brackets, subscripts, superscripts, displaystyle

By using the following code from the `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx,mathtools}
\DeclareSymbolFont{Xlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xsum}{\mathop}{Xlargesymbols}{80}

\begin{document}
   \begin{align*}
   \text{repeat until convergence:}
   \begin{cases}
       \theta_0:=\theta_0-\alpha\frac{1}{m} \Xsum_{i=1}^{m}(h_\theta(x)-y_i)
       \\
       \theta_1:=\theta_1-\alpha\frac{1}{m} \Xsum_{i=1}^{m}(h_\theta(x)-y_i)x_i
    \end{cases}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I've achieved the following expression:

[image: Gradient Descent]

But I would like that the subscripts and the superscripts of the summations look like this:

[image: Gradient Descent]

If it is possible, how could it be changed?

Comment: The usual way to set limits in that manner is `\sum\limits`.  You don't say how `\Xsum` is defined, so I can't help more.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I want to thank you for the observation. I edited to correct this error.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution using `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` for the font of the clone of Times New Roman:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\let\sum\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{cmlargesymbols}{"50}

\begin{document}
\[\text{repeat until convergence:}\begin{cases}
    \theta_0\coloneqq\theta_0-\alpha\dfrac{1}{m} \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{m}(h_\theta(x)-y_i)
    \\
    \theta_1\coloneqq\theta_1-\alpha\dfrac{1}{m} \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{m}(h_\theta(x)-y_i)x_i
\end{cases}\]
\end{document}
```

PS: The comment of @barbara beeton is correct to the 100%. I have used `\displaystyle` instead of `\sum\limits`.

[image]